# Listing file names using FXML TableView - unable to populate data

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, fxml

I am trying to populate filesnames in a tabular format using FXML.

I am able to display the table but the rows are not getting displayed.

Directory name will be selected by user during runtime.

[image: screenshot of the current FXML window].

Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            AnchorPane root =(AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Utility.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,600);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("testing");
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

AppController.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.DirectoryChooser;

public class AppController
{
    @FXML private Label BrowseStatus;
    @FXML private TextField TDpath;
    @FXML private Button CreateH2H;
    @FXML private TableView<String> FileListTable;
    @FXML private TableColumn<FilesInDir,String> FileNameCol;
    @FXML private ObservableList<String> fidlist;

    @FXML 
    protected void handleBrowseWindowsExplorer(ActionEvent event){
        DirectoryChooser TestDataDir = new DirectoryChooser();
        TestDataDir.setTitle("Select path");
        File selectedDir = TestDataDir.showDialog(null);
        if(selectedDir == null){
            BrowseStatus.setText("Nothing choosen");
            TDpath.setText("");
        } else {
            TDpath.setText(selectedDir.getAbsolutePath());
            FileListTable = new TableView<String>();
            FileNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<FilesIndDir,String>("FileName"));
            FileListTable.setPlaceholder(BrowseStatus);
            BrowseStatus.setText("Folder has been selected");
            File tFile = new File(TDpath.getText());
            File[] listOfFiles = tFile.listFiles();
            fidlist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            List<String> fileNameList = null;
            for (int i=0; i<listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                fileNameList = Arrays.asList(listOfFiles[i].getName());
            }
            fidlist.addAll(fileNamesList);
            FileListTable.setItems(fidlist);
        }
    }
}
```

Utility.fxml

```
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.collection.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory?>

<AnchorPane fx:controller="application.AppController" id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <children>
        <GridPane>
            <children>
                <MenuBar maxWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="800.0" GridPane.ColumnIndex="0" GridPane.RowIndex="0">
                    <menus>
                        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                            <items>
                                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
                            </items>
                        </Menu>
                    </menus>
                </MenuBar>
                <BorderPane GridPane.ColumnIndex="0" GridPane.RowIndex="1">
                    <top>
                    <TabPane PrefHeight="700.0" PrefWidth="900.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
                        <Tab text="Files tab ">
                            <content>
                                <GridPane hgap="10" vgap="10">
                                    <padding><Insets top="25" right="25" bottom="10" left="25" /></padding>
                                    <children>
                                        <Label text="Path :" GridPane.ColumnIndex="0" GridPane.RowIndex="1" />
                                        <TextField fx:id="TDpath" GridPane.ColumnIndex="0" GridPane.RowIndex="1" />
                                        <Button text="Browse" onAction="#handleBrowseWindowsExplorer" GridPane.ColumnIndex="3" GridPane.RowIndex="1" />
                                        <VBox prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="400.0" spacing="6.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.ColumnIndex="0" GridPane.RowIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="4" >
                                        <children>
                                            <TableView fx:id="FileListTable" >
                                                <placeholder><Label fx:id="BrowseStatus" text="No files in selected directory" /></placeholder>
                                                <columns>
                                                    <TableColumn fx:id="FileNameCol" text="File Names" prefWidth="400">
                                                        <cellValueFactory>
                                                            <PropertyValueFactory property="FileName" />
                                                        </cellValueFactory>
                                                    </TableColumn>
                                                </columns>
                                            </TableView>
                                        </children>
                                        </VBox>
                                    </children>
                                </GridPane>
                            </content>
                        </Tab>
                    </TabPane>
                </top>
                </BorderPane>
            </children>
        </GridPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

FilesInDir.java

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class FilesInDir {
    private final SimpleStringProperty FileName = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public FilesInDir(String fName) {
        setFileName(fName);
    }

    public String FileNameProperty() {
        return FileName.get();
    }

    public void setFileName(String fName) {
        this.Filename.set(fName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course you are not able to do anything with uncompileable code. Also there are that many errors in the code that I advise you go through a tutorial.

Comment: You got this line to compile: `file[] listOfFiles = tFile.listFiles();` ??? And then there is `FilesIndDir`. And that's only the tip of the iceberg. `"application.css".toExternalForm()`???

Comment: not in java. It's **F**ile, capital letter! Case matters in java. And if you even got to display something you are using a different FXML, since a `Tab` is not a `Node` and therefore cannot be added as `top` node in a `BorderPane`.

Comment: @fabian, reg: top node -- that's a good catch. I missed to put that tag while creating the question. Actually, I had this tag info in my eclipse. But, I missed to put the same. 
Original issue still not resolved. Data is not populated in the table . Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer I'll just ignore all the typos, since there seems to be a compilable version of the code and point out the other errors:

#### `FilesInDir`

If I got your intention, this class should contain the info for a file that should be displayed. Besides ignoring the naming convention of starting identifiers of class members with a lowercase letter, the real issue here is the `FileNameProperty`. The property method with the suffix `Property` has to return the property itself and `PropertyValueFactory` relies on that fact. It should look like this:

```
public StringProperty fileNameProperty() {
    return FileName;
}
```

Also you did not use the class as type parameter of your `TableView`:

```
@FXML
private TableView<FilesInDir> FileListTable;
```

#### `AppController.handleBrowseWindowsExplorer`

The main issue is in this method:

1. There's no need to need to make `fidlist` a field, let alone annotate it with `@FXML`. In fact there's no need to create a new `ObservableList` at all.
2. You recreate the `TableView`, that was created and injected by the `FXMLLoader` and do not insert it to the scene graph, but you work with the new `TableView`, which is not the one that is displayed on screen.
3. If no file is selected, the `TextField` is emptied, but the items in the `TableView` from a previously selected directory remain, leading to inconsistent behaviour.
4. `fileNameList = Arrays.asList(listOfFiles[i].getName());` in the `for` loop replaces the list with a new `List` containing a single element every time it's executed.
5. `File tFile = new File(TDpath.getText());` recreates the file from the `String` that was created by converting the selected file to a `String`. That's just unnecessary; you should simply use `selectedDir`

Changing the method like this should work, assuming you fixed the points mentioned for `FilesInDir` too:

```
@FXML
protected void handleBrowseWindowsExplorer(ActionEvent event) {
    DirectoryChooser TestDataDir = new DirectoryChooser();
    TestDataDir.setTitle("Select path");
    File selectedDir = TestDataDir.showDialog(null);

    if (selectedDir == null) {
        BrowseStatus.setText("Nothing choosen");
        FileListTable.getItems().clear();
        TDpath.setText("");
    } else {
        TDpath.setText(selectedDir.getAbsolutePath());
        BrowseStatus.setText("Folder has been selected");
        File[] listOfFiles = selectedDir.listFiles();

        ArrayList<FilesInDir> fidlist = new ArrayList<>(listOfFiles.length);

        for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles) {
            fidlist.add(new FilesInDir(listOfFile.getName()));
        }

        FileListTable.getItems().setAll(fidlist);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestions. Now, I see a improvement in my tableview. The table is being updated with number of files. i.e. It is creating a scrollbar & formatted rows based on the number of files. But, the filename is not displayed. I did verify from my end, with below lines of code. Nothing is written on the console by this piece of code.      `public SimpleStringProperty fileNameProperty()
    {
     System.out.println("In FilesInDIr Class, getting now : " + this.FileName);
        return FileName;
    } ` Now the pending issue lies with returning the data.

Comment: Marked as "Answered" as it resolved the basic issue with code & many improvements to the code. Thank @fabian. I am still working on data printing. I'll post final code once I fix the 'data return' issue.

Comment: @Raju: If you use the property with a lowercase `f`, you have to modify the value factory in the fxml too: `<PropertyValueFactory property="fileName" />`; otherwise it uses the getters, but even with the wrong case I still see the file names in the table.

Comment: after editing filename in fxml, the values are getting displayed. But same value getting displayed for all the file names in directory

Comment: I have added this code piece into FilesInDir class `public FilesInDir()
    {
     this("");
    }` then issue got fixed. All the files displayed properly.